# Which React shouldComponentUpdate rendering strategy is correct of the following?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. List every prop I need to render

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.color !== nextProps.color) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this.state.count !== nextState.count) {
      return true;
    }
    ...
    ...
    return false;

  }
```

2. Use the following same function

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return (JSON.stringify(nextProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.props) || JSON.stringify(nextState) !== JSON.stringify(this.state));
    }
```

3. React.Purecomponent

Also, I was wondering if only 'shallow compare' is ok or I should consider 'deep compare' like the number 2. Does 'deep compare' cost less than 're-render' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the thing to be aware of, is that by default a component will render if:

1. Its props change
2. Its state changes
3. Its parent renders.

Now it's this third scenario that is usually the problem, as say you have a parent component like:

```
render() {
    return <div> 
        <CompA value = {this.state.a}/>
        <CompB>
        <CompB>
        <CompB>
        <CompB>
    </div>
}
```

And in this scenario the parent component's `state.a` value is changing every second, and therefore rendering, and therefore each of the `CompB` render methods will fire, even though they're not going to be different.

This is problematic when you have a tree with thousands of components, or if each of those `CompB` had a thousands of components inside of them, each of them also firing their render methods.

Secondly, *a render is not the same as a DOM update*. That is - the render method is just React checking if the DOM needs to be updated. If no updates are required, React won't do any DOM updates.

So, React provides a way to optimise, to opt out of these render methods being called.

Remember that `shouldComponentUpdate` and `PureComponent` are *optimisation only*. They shouldn't be used to control what is rendered. (That is - you should assume that the render method will always be fired, even if you've prevented it in your `shouldComponentUpdate`).

So the question is - should you use `componentShouldUpdate` or `PureComponent`?

Well - PureComponent just does a shallow comparison on the props.

I would argue that PureComponent should be enough, it saves muddying up your code with manually writing a `shouldComponentUpdate` function.

Where you potentially would run into problems if you have nested objects in state *and* you are mutating them.

Here is an example:

```js
class CompA extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { value, foo } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>value: {value}</p>
        <p>foo: {JSON.stringify(foo)}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      foo: {
        bar: {
          biz: "bang"
        }
      },
      a: "value"
    };
  }

  handleFooClickC = () => {
    const mutatedFoo = this.state.foo;
    //You shouldn't be doing this anyway. 
    mutatedFoo.bar.biz = Math.random();
    this.setState({ foo: mutatedFoo });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleFooClickC}>Change Foo C</button>
        <CompA value={this.state.value} foo={this.state.foo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pure-components-and-state-mutation-po8du)

In this scenario `CompA` doesn't become aware that the `foo` object has changed, because it is still the same object.

Now - you shouldn't be mutating state like this anyway - precisely because of problems like this, but in the case that you are working on a codebase that does have state mutation like this, then this is the pitfall to watch out for if you were to switch all of your `Components` to `PureComponents`.

In scenarios where you *replace* the object, this won't be a problem. See the Code Sandbox for examples.

Re: the cost of comparison - I couldn't find details of what the PureComponent shallow compare actually does, I suspect it's an object equality comparison, but don't take my word on that.

**Conclusion**

Using PureComponent should be enough. Remember that this is for optimisation only, and so IMO there's no point muddying up your code unnecessarily.

Where you might have problems with PureComponent is if you are mutating state, in which case consider using `forceUpdate`, or just remove the state mutation, or maybe in that scenario you want to be manually defining the shouldComponentUpdate function.